# catalog/product/list.phtml insert text before price IF within certain category

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

How do I write this line so that the text "Starts at" appears before the price of simple products but only within the categories with IDs 3, 10, 25, 26, 27, 28, 11, 12, 29, 13, 14, 7?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $category = Mage::registry('current_category');?>
<?php if ($category && in_array($category->getId(), array(3, 10, 25, 26, 27, 28, 11, 12, 29, 13, 14, 7))) : ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('Start at:')?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Not sure why I was unable to get this to work. What would it look like if I used the category name instead of its ID?

Comment: `in_array($category->getName(), array('name 1', 'name 2', ...)`

Comment: I must have the wrong template. Maybe it should be in price.phtml

Comment: Currently configurable product prices begin with 'Starts at:' Where does that text live?